# Regex to remove all special characters from string?

Tags: c#, regex, string

I'm completely incapable of regular expressions, and so I need some help with a problem that I think would best be solved by using regular expressions.

I have list of strings in C#:

```
List<string> lstNames = new List<string>();
lstNames.add("TRA-94:23");
lstNames.add("TRA-42:101");
lstNames.add("TRA-109:AD");

foreach (string n in lstNames) {
  // logic goes here that somehow uses regex to remove all special characters
  string regExp = "NO_IDEA";
  string tmp = Regex.Replace(n, regExp, "");
}
```

I need to be able to loop over the list and return each item without any special characters. For example, item one would be "TRA9423", item two would be "TRA42101" and item three would be TRA109AD.

Is there a regular expression that can accomplish this for me?

Also, the list contains more than 4000 items, so I need the search and replace to be efficient and quick if possible.

EDIT:
I should have specified that any character beside a-z, A-Z and 0-9 is special in my circumstance.

Comment: 4000 is a very small number of items. Why is it so important that the answer is efficient and quick rather than for example readable and maintainable? Have you measured a performance issue here?

Comment: @Mark - this is just my ignorance showing, I suppose. 4000 seems to me to be a lot, but I'm apparently wrong. I've done no benchmarks, but the regex seems to be very fast anyway, so I don't think I need to mess around with speeding anything up. I'd actually simplified my example a little, because I didn't want to needlessly convolute my question. I actually have a list of complex class objects, and I'm using the .FindAll with a delegate function to find all matches. The regex comes into play in a property on my class that uses the regex to manipulate a certain string for the delegate function.

Comment: Thank you all for your help! Would that all questions were easy like this for geniuses like yourselves. :D

Answer (score 131, accepted):

It really depends on your definition of special characters. I find that a whitelist rather than a blacklist is the best approach in most situations:

```
tmp = Regex.Replace(n, "[^0-9a-zA-Z]+", "");
```

You should be careful with your current approach because the following two items will be converted to the same string and will therefore be indistinguishable:

```
"TRA-12:123"
"TRA-121:23"
```

Comment: The `+` quantifier is redundant. If the character matches, it will also match in a consecutive sequence of these.

Comment: @Daniel, i'd expect the `+` to make the operation considerably faster, of course it won't really matter unless your processing something huge.

Comment: It doesn't matter that both items would end up being the same, because I'm doing a fuzzy match and I expect to have multiple items returned. 
List<PdfAndXml> lstPax = lstReports.FindAll(delegate(PdfAndXml o) { return (o.Packed.Contains(findTxt)); });
Packed is the property where I'm using the regex to manipulate a certain string attribute of the PdfAndXml class.

Comment: Love the "whitelist" idea!

Comment: so ^ means not in regex?

Comment: ^ means not WITHIN a character group [] when it occurs right at the start of the group. Outside of a character group it means the start of the string or the start of the line, depending on the way you've set up your regex; usually with a flag at the same point you'd specify case (in)sensitivity.

Answer (score 19):

`[^a-zA-Z0-9]` is a character class matches any non-alphanumeric characters.

Alternatively, `[^\w\d]` does the same thing.

Usage:

```
string regExp = "[^\w\d]";
string tmp = Regex.Replace(n, regExp, "");
```

Comment: I tested both of these versions on http://regexpal.com/ and found that "[^\w\d]" would not match underscore characters while [^a-zA-Z0-9] would.

Answer (score 17):

This should do it:

```
[^a-zA-Z0-9]
```

Basically it matches all non-alphanumeric characters.

Answer (score 9):

You can use:

```
string regExp = "\\W";
```

This is equivalent to Daniel's "`[^a-zA-Z0-9]`"

\W matches any nonword character. Equivalent to the Unicode categories `[^\p{Ll}\p{Lu}\p{Lt}\p{Lo}\p{Nd}\p{Pc}]`.

Comment: also matches _ so not quite perfect here.

Comment: Ummm, you're right - wouldn't have thought so from the description. Well spotted.

Answer (score 5):

For my purposes I wanted all English ASCII chars, so this worked.

```
html = Regex.Replace(html, "[^\x00-\x80]+", "")
```

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your definition of "special character", I think "[^a-zA-Z0-9]" would probably do the trick. That would find anything that is not a small letter, a capital letter, or a digit.

Comment: Oh, I notice a pattern developing in the answers.

Answer (score 2):

```
tmp = Regex.Replace(n, @"\W+", "");
```

`\w` matches letters, digits, and underscores, `\W` is the negated version.

Comment: Since you define _ as special you should go with one of the other answers :)

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want to use Regex then another option is to use

```
char.IsLetterOrDigit
```

You can use this to loop through each char of the string and only return if true.

Answer (score -2):

```
public static string Letters(this string input)
{
    return string.Concat(input.Where(x => char.IsLetter(x) && !char.IsSymbol(x) && !char.IsWhiteSpace(x)));
}
```