# Encoding issues - code generating garbled characters in c#

Tags: c#, openxml

My program is generating a word document by reading another file, but the outpout generates garbled characters example: its generating "Â Q4Â testÂ text", when the output should be "Q4 test text"
So far I think its an encoding issue and it looks the following code might need to be changed to fix the issue:

byte[] bytes = file.OpenBinary();

This reads the file, but it looks the encoding is not correct and when the code manipulates and writes this file back, it generates garbled characters.
I've researched google and stackExchange and tried few things to fix this, but none of these seems to fix the issue:

```
//Alternate code 1      
        var sourceBytes = file.OpenBinary();
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.Convert(Encoding.Default, Encoding.UTF8, sourceBytes);
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.Convert(Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.UTF32, sourceBytes);

//Alternate code 2
        System.Text.UTF8Encoding enc = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
        string s = enc.GetString(sourceBytes);
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s);

//Alternate code 3
        var stream = file.OpenBinaryStream();
        var sr = new StreamReader(stream);
        var sw = new StreamWriter(stream);
        var s = sr.ReadToEnd();
        s += "AAA";
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s);
```

Comment: Why are you reading a text file as binary? There's no reason to and it would probably work just fine if you just read it normally.

Comment: Just use `File.ReadAllText()` or `XElement.Load()`

Comment: Many thanks for reply.
My program needs to read an InfoPath form get the Rich text and then output that into an existing Word document.
This seems to be OK and I'm also using Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(rtfValue) to make sure that its UTF8.
But when I read existing Word document which is SPFile object in SharePoint, it does not give me an option like File.ReadAllText(path, Encoding.Default) as you suggested.
I'm quite new to OpenXML and Sharepoint, and I just cannot seem to be able to fix this issue, please help!!

Comment: I've also tried following that also fails: 
   SPFile file = lib.RootFolder.Files["Template.docx"]

                        byte[] templateBytes = file.OpenBinary();

                        string s = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(templateBytes);
                        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
                        doc.LoadXml(s);
                        s = doc.InnerXml;
                        templateBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s);

Comment: I also posted another question that might give some more background:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16171488/openxml-infopath-richtext-box-to-word-document-gives-formatting-errors