# replacing special characters with a specific special character

Tags: javascript

I have a string which is exactly like this...

R%26B,Alternative,Rock,Classic Rock,Heavy Metal,Classical,Reggae%2fSka,

I have tried enough to remove the special characters before they reach the browser...but not going anywhere..so planing to rely on my old and trusted friend "javascript" I want it to read

R&B,Alternative,Rock,Classic Rock,Heavy Metal,Classical,Reggae&Ska,

I know this can be done through regular expression which I am just not able to figure it out. How would I write the expression?

Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try using:

```
decodeURIComponent("R%26B,Alternative,Rock,Classic Rock,Heavy Metal,Classical,Reggae%26Ska")
//^prints^ "R&B,Alternative,Rock,Classic Rock,Heavy Metal,Classical,Reggae&Ska"
```

Comment: @Arvind--totally worked..thanks for the direction. This was good because I could pop this bad boy in server side since I am using server side javascript

Answer (score 1):

Probably you need decodeURIComponent() function.

```
<script>
 var decodedString = decodeURIComponent('R%26B,Alternative,Rock,Classic Rock,Heavy Metal,Classical,Reggae%2fSka');
</script>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_decodeuricomponent.asp

Answer (score 1):

Look at these answers:

[Regex to remove all special characters from string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3303420/regex-to-remove-all-special-characters-from-string)

They layout a regex that will remove everything EXCEPT those characters you want to allow, this is safer then removing a list of %26,%2f, etc.

For example...

[^0-9a-zA-Z, ]+ would allow all letters, numbers, commas and whitespace.

[^0-9a-zA-Z]+ would be only letters and numbers

The other answers are probably pointing you in a better direction... if it means fixing the string before it gets to the client.