# Regex extract 16 digit of contract Number

Tags: c#, regex

Our customer usually send us some message which included their contract number. Our contract number formats are a string of 16 digits starts from 1000 (ex: 1000117030010745).

Right now our tool can recognize the contract number which are well placed using regex to find 16 digits placing right next to each other.

But the problem is, sometimes they include some special characters like dots(.), space etc... in the middle of the contract number and the number of those character are not constant.
ex: 10001170.5102.1428 or 1000 11706 0056941.

Is there any regex that can matching those number out?

Thank you!

Edit 1: There might be a chance that the citizen ID is placed next to the contract number, separated by a space. And some customer ad both "special character" to the contract number

ex: 1000.1170. 1000.3828

Comment: Remove anything that is one of those "special characters" and then validate

Comment: [`([0-9][ .]?){16}`](https://regex101.com/r/JVSGWy/1)

Comment: Or perhaps [`\b1([ .]?0){3}([ .]?\d){12}\b`](https://regex101.com/r/3WA3Yz/1)?

Comment: @horcrux: your answer is best so far but there are chance that both space and dot are added next to each other like: 1000.1170. 1000.3828. Any suggestion?

Comment: Use `*` or `{0,2}` instead of `?`. Sorry, but have you ever wrote a regular expression?

Answer (score 1):

There is a very similar problem here:
[Regex to remove all special characters from string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3303420/regex-to-remove-all-special-characters-from-string)

Add a reference to the namespace

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
```

then in your body

```
// Example
string startNumber = "100.23 455 * 4332";

// Replace anything but numbers 0-9 with nothing
string formattedNumber = Regex.Replace(startNumber, [^0-9], "" ); 

// formattedNumber = 100234554332
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get contract number value using this line

```js
var string='AASHGHSABCD1000. 65 .893 4652345EFGHIJKLMNASASOP'
var res = string.replace(/[^a-zA-Z 0-9]+/g,'').replace(/\s/g, '').substr(string.indexOf("1000"), 16);
alert(res)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

remove any non-digit chars with `[^\d]` and validate 16 digit input with `^$` (start and end with)

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class MainClass {

  public static void Main (string[] args) {
    // valid 16 digit
    string citizenID = "1000.1170. 1000.3826";
    // not valid more than 16 digit
    //string citizenID = "1000.1170. 1000.3826789";
    citizenID = Regex.Replace(citizenID, @"[^\d]", ""); 
    Match match = Regex.Match(citizenID, @"^\d{16}$");
    if(match.Success)
      Console.WriteLine ("valid citizenID: " + citizenID);
    else
      Console.WriteLine ("not valid citizenID");
  }
}
```